# Get an authentication token while routing in camel

Tags: java, web-services, authentication, apache-camel

I'm trying to expose a service that needs authentication, but I want to make it transparent to the client

The route looks like this:

1. client sends a POST
2. camel calls the WS using config parameters and gets the authentication token
3. camel calls the WS using client's POST data **and the token**

I thought "enrich" was the answer but it will route the initial POST to the enricher endpoint.

Is there a way to get the token and put it as a header of the message?

Comment: Add a processor in which you call the WS without the original post contents.

Comment: @Namphibian Do you mean calling the WS without Camel or using `template.sendBody("an endpoint", "some data")`?
And that would be a sync call. What if I want an async one? Is it possible?
thanks